# Singular Value Decomposition Column Space and Row Space

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, singular-values

I was listening to a lecture by Gilbert Strang and he said that in a SVD, the columns of $U$ are in the column space of $A$...

$$
\begin{aligned}
  A &= U \Sigma V^T \\
  AV &= U \Sigma
\end{aligned}
$$

so we can clearly see by this calculation that U is a combination of the columns of $A$, but then he said that $V$ was in the rowspace of $A$ which I was having a hard time justifying because he did not give an explanation for it. If I try the same thing I see

$$
U^TA = \Sigma V^T
$$

does multiplying from the left give a combination of the rows? or is there another way to justify this?

Comment: Taking the transpose of both sides of $A = U \Sigma V^T$ shows that $A^T = V \Sigma^T U^T$. This reveals that the columns of $V$ are in the column space of $A^T$.

Comment: ah ok that makes sense. Thanks. If you post as an answer ill accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transpose both sides of your equation $U^T A = \Sigma V^T$ to see that
$$
A^T U = V \Sigma^T.
$$
This shows that the columns of $V$ are in the column space of $A^T$.